# Can't convert tab-delimited values from string to float

Tags: python

Data in my .dat file are arranged like:

```
1.5     673.68709333206604217
4.5     284.69148000018861264
7.5     120.2999666666908732
```

I am trying to plot with matplotlib. Here is the code for reading the data:

```py
with open ('Sizedist_N10000_a0.1_t6500_E100000_n1.dat', 'r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = '\t')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))
```

But it shows the error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.5     673.68709333206604217'

What can I do?

Comment: sounds like your data aren't actually tab-delimited, but instead space-delimited

Comment: no, my data is tab-delimited, i copied here from my data, but tabs are showing as spaces here. I don't know how to specify a tab here.

Comment: in that case, you don't need a `csv.reader` for tab-delimited data. loop through the file directly and split each row, e.g., : `_x, _y = row.split(); x.append(float(_x))`

Comment: and if you have pandas installed, `pandas.read_csv` will make your life even easier

Comment: I edited your question to remove reference to matplotlib, since matplotlib is not a factor or part of this question and issue

Comment: I tried your code on my own laptop and I could reproduce the problem at first. I use PyCharm. I copy-pasted your CSV file into a new CSV file and pressed the tab key to replace the spaces by tabs. But a closer inspection showed me that PyCharm replaced the tabs by spaces automatically. I had to use the command "To Tabs" to force using tabs. After that, your code worked fine. So I agree with Paul H that the CSV file is not tab-delimited.

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because the file isn't a comma separated file.
Also, to still extract data, you haven't split the row into individual values

> Instead, you can get the individual values in a row by using split() function

```
with open ('Sizedist_N10000_a0.1_t6500_E100000_n1.dat', 'r') as csvfile:
    plots = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = '\n'))
    print(plots)
    for plot in plots:
        rX, rY = plot[0].split()
        x.append(float(rX))
        y.append(float(rY))
```